# Granting access to view but not the underlying tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets say I have three schemas, `a`, `b` and `c` in an Oracle database.

I have a table, `a.t`.

I have a view, `b.v`, which is just view on `a.t` (in the real case there is actually `a.t1`, `a.t2` etc).

I want to grant `c` select access on `b.v` but not `a.t`.

What are the grants I have to issue for `a.t` and `b.v`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by grant the `SELECT PRIVILEGE` to user `'a'` `WITH GRANT OPTION`

Grant user b to select a.t:

```
GRANT SELECT ON a.t TO b WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Grant user c to select on b.v:

```
GRANT SELECT ON b.v TO c;
```